# Manual route doesn't work in Windows 10

Tags: windows, route, static-routes

I'm struggling to make a **static route** working in Windows 10 and on a specific PC: it doesn't seem to do its job.

Here's the route table before:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 27...84 a9 XX XX XX XX ......Realtek PCi GBE Family Controller #2
 26...04 d3 XX XX XX XX ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #3
 11...06 d3 XX XX XX XX ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #4
 12...04 d3 XX XX XX XX ......Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 #2
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.7    105
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.1.7    301
      192.168.1.7  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.7    301
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.7    301
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.7    301
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.7    301
===========================================================================
 Persistent Routes:
   None
```

As you can see the Wi-Fi card (with automatic metric) is assigned an IP **192.168.1.7** by the router 192.168.1.1; I want all the traffic to **192.168.0.0/24** to be forwared to 192.168.1.253.

So I add the (temporary) route with:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>route ADD 192.168.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.253
 OK
```

Then I check with **route print** again and it seems OK:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 27...84 a9 XX XX XX XX ......Realtek PCi GBE Family Controller #2
 26...04 d3 XX XX XX XX ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #3
 11...06 d3 XX XX XX XX ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #4
 12...04 d3 XX XX XX XX ......Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 #2
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.7    105
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.1.253      192.168.1.7     46
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.1.7    301
      192.168.1.7  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.7    301
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.7    301
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.7    301
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.7    301
===========================================================================
 Persistent Routes:
   None
```

I can also see the route with:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>route print 192.168.0.*
===========================================================================
Interface List
 27...84 a9 XX XX XX XX ......Realtek PCi GBE Family Controller #2
 26...04 d3 XX XX XX XX ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #3
 11...06 d3 XX XX XX XX ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #4
 12...04 d3 XX XX XX XX ......Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 #2
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.1.253      192.168.1.7     46
===========================================================================
 Persistent Routes:
   None
```

But when pinging I have no reply at all by any of the 192.168.0.0/24 IPs.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping 192.168.0.1

Pinging 192.168.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping 192.168.1.253

Pinging 192.168.1.253 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.253: bytes=32 time=117ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.253: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.253: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=128
^C

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.253:
    Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 3, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 4ms, Maximum = 117ms, Average = 41ms

C:\WINDOWS\system32>tracert 192.168.0.1

  1     *           *           *   Request timeout.
  2     *           *           *   Request timeout.
  3     *           *           *   Request timeout.
  4     *           *           *   Request timeout.
  5 ^C
```

I'm sure the 192.168.1.253 forwards the packets correctly because I used another router + another PC with the same route command and it works, but I need to make this router (192.168.1.1) and this PC (192.168.1.7) work. Also, I cannot add the static route on the router itself (192.168.1.1) because it doesn't support this feature.

EDIT 1: There is of course a static route on the 192.168.0.1 router that forwards all the 192.168.1.0/24 traffic on the IP 192.168.0.112, which is another interface on the same device that has 192.168.1.253. On this device I can ping every other device of the two networks.

EDIT 2: I tried also disabling the firewall on the PC (192.168.1.7) but unbelievably it still doesn't work.

Comment: this is not an answer - but in order to get ping to work, the devices on 192.168.0.0/24 need a route *back* to your Win10 box. The ping packet may be reaching them... if there is no route back you also get the symptoms shown above - i.e. Request timeout. So is the other router pushing different routes to the other devices?

Comment: `Also, I cannot add the static route on the router itself (192.168.1.1) because it doesn't support this feature.` - Router that doesn't support static routes? That's somewhat suspect. How do you know it doesn't support static routes?

Comment: @MNB Yes, of course, I didn't specified that I did that on the 192.168.0.1 router.

Comment: @joeqwerty Because it is a modem/router supplied by an ISP with a firmware with "basic" features (too basic!!!) that doesn't allow to set static routes.